# Ground planing H-bridge and drivers

Tags: dc, converter, routing, ground-plane

I'm currently routing a DC/DC converter using a controller that need an external H-Bridge. As I wanted to reduce the noise at the controller level (to preserve the measures it makes clean), I started by creating a start ground plane where the H-bridge's and the controller's ground plans are only connected near the power supply, as described by the following picture:

[image]

But doing this, it raised a few questions:

- Will this design induces current loops at the gates signals level?
- Will the impedance change over the gap be strong enough to perturb those signals?
- Same with the feedback lines that come from the H-bridge side and that I try to keep away from noise.

In your opinion, will this star-shaped ground plane be better than a simple solid plan under the whole PCB?

Thanks

Comment: I think the gap makes it worse. The ground returns for the signals between the driver and H-bridge have to pass trough the power supply where (potentially) large currents flowing trough ground (return current from the H-bridge load) could cause ground bounce. A normal full ground plane would be better imho.

Comment: I should use 4 planes for such applications. One plane is for ground, another for +V.

Comment: Considering the gate currents, the FET drivers need to be on the H-bridge side of the split. You may control the drivers across a split with suitable care; the currents are much lower.

Comment: Listen to @Antonio51. Go for two solid planes throughout! _”I try to keep away from noise”_ I was thinking the se when I started but you don’t want two slightly different grounds, which will cause all kinds of problems. Two solid planes and very strong decoupling is the way to go.

Comment: @winny  Thanks. :-) The profit of two planes is that the "power" loop is very "short" (only 1.5 mm or lower). So minimalist additional "parasitic" inductance ... This "technical" view is largely used for "large" IGBT devices made with a number of "little" IGBT.

Comment: Thank all. I think I'll go with a solid plane
@Antonio51 My bad, I didn't give you enough information. It's going to be a 4-layer board, with this stack [Top signals | GND | VCCs | Bottom signals ]. I would have prefer keeping at least one of my two signals layers between the GND and the VCCs layers but I need to keep the signals traces accessible for debug purpose  for now

Comment: No worries ... good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have made your decision and already had some good input but I'm going go ahead and answer this anyway and give some explanation.

Yes to all 3 questions. The gap creates an undefined return path with parasitic loop inductance. This area becomes a strong emitter/receiver of EMI and is not recommended in general. (see my last sentence)

Grounding mixed signal PCBs is obviously a complex topic with many problems and solutions with more grey answers than black and white.

The three most common options for grounding in a system that includes varying signal sections with a single return point to a power supply:

- Star grounding with power and ground rails/pours
- A single ground plane to provide a single reference potential throughout the entire system
- Multiple physically separated ground planes for different types of signals

The first two recommendations are most relevant in today's electronics for multiple reasons. Between these, most designers will recommend the second approach. If you look closely, you'll find that the first two points are equivalent as long as you do not route over any gaps between ground regions.

When someone says to keep your analog and digital grounds separate, most suddenly assume this means they should use physically disconnected ground planes, but this is not the meaning of the recommendation. This is where the original recommendations for physically separate ground planes arise, and it's one reason they persist today.

When I say "physically separate ground planes" or "physically disconnected ground planes," I'm referring to two ground sections that have absolutely no physical electrical connection between them. There is one corner case I can think of where this is acceptable, but this amounts to placing two physically separated, electrically isolated devices on the same PCB substrate, which is a totally pointless exercise. I think this keeps popping up because everyone forgets how return currents and parasitics work. The single ground plane is "less bad" for many reasons but it would be wise to read up on EMI and return paths if you want a deeper dive.